# Display data from text file

Tags: php

I'm a newbie in php. The thing is i have a text file that contain this data. The data is sorted this way in the text file.

1

Premier Hospital
PTB 1600, Road 13
 
Salford City
5000 Manchester, England

2

TSH Hospital
760, Birmingham Road
82000 Birmingham, England

3

St Andrew Hospital
 
58, City Road
700 Sydney, Australia

4

Andrew Clinic
No. 11, Cherry Road
90000, Perth
Australia

I manage to read the text file by using this code:

```
$file = fopen("newFile.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
while (!feof($file)){   
    $data = fgets($file); 
    echo str_replace('\r\n','',$data);
}

fclose($file);
```

but the output is diplay like this:

1 Premier Hospital PTB 1600, Road 13 Salford City 5000 Manchester, England 2 TSH Hospital 760, Birmingham Road 82000 Birmingham, England 3 St Andrew Hospital 58, City Road 700 Sydney, Australia 4 Andrew Clinic No. 11, Cherry Road 90000, Perth Australia

My question is how can I change the output into this using php without changing the text file:

1 Premier Hospital PTB 1600, Road 13 Salford City 5000 Manchester, England
2 TSH Hospital 760, Birmingham Road 82000 Birmingham, England
3 St Andrew Hospital 58, City Road 700 Sydney, Australia
4 Andrew Clinic No. 11, Cherry Road 90000, Perth Australia

Comment: It looks like you want to preserve some newline characters but not others so you'll have to parse the file line by line. Also use `<br/>` instead of `\n` if you want to echo in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to read content line by line:

```
<?php

$fp = fopen('sample.txt','r');
while ($text = fgets($fp)) {
  echo $text;
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: I've done that. But the output is display just like inside the text file. I need to display the output just like the one on my question and I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets to get the text line by line :

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```